# Using aggregate function in custom function

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I need to calculate the rms (root mean square) for different columns.
To not repeat myself I would like to create a custom aggregate function `rms(numeric)` which should do the following calculation:

```
SELECT SQRT(AVG(POWER(v, 2))) AS rms
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) AS vals (v);
```

The function should be called like the following:

```
SELECT RMS(v)
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) AS vals (v);
```

In both cases the output should be a floating number. In my example `3.3166...`.

I found several easy examples on how to create custom aggregate functions, but I could not find an example which explains how to use another aggregate function (in my case `AVG()`) within the custom aggregate function.

I also found the question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667245/writing-my-own-aggregate-function-in-postgresql), which asks essentially the same thing. But the accepted answer recreates `MAX`. I would prefer not to recreate existing functions.

Answer (score 1):

You would not use another aggregate function.  You would define your aggregate "from scratch".  I am surprised there is not an existing aggregate that does this, but I have not found one.